# Python Pandas phone numbers cleaning by eliminating consecutive repeated characters

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a retail dataset that consists of uncleaned mobile phone numbers. I have data like this

| Phone Number |
| --- |
| 03451000000 |
| 03451000001 |
| 03451010101 |
| 03451111111 |
| 03459999999 |
| 03459090909 |

Now there is a very high probability that the above phone numbers are fakely entered by cashier. The genuine number looks like this for example 03453485413.

There are two important things:

1. The length of the string is always fixed 11 characters
2. The phone number always starts with 03*********

Now how do I eliminate phone numbers based on the rule that, for example, character repetition of more than 5 times eliminated?

Comment: Regex is your salvation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex to find such patters.

For example:
`(\d)\1{4,}`

This will match a digit and check if it repeats itself 4 more times. This is the case in examples 1, 2, 4 & 5

Another example is: `(\d\d)\1{2,}`

This will match 2 digits and checks if it repeats itself 2 more times. This is the case in examples 1, 3, 4, 5 & 6